# How can i send sms after successful user registration using spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, sms, using

After successful account creation, i have to send an sms to the associated customer.

For this purpose i have exposed sms service as an advice as below.

```
package com.naresh.advice;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.AfterReturning;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.naresh.dto.AccountDTO;
import com.naresh.dto.CustomerDTO;
import com.twilio.Twilio;
import com.twilio.rest.api.v2010.account.Message;
import com.twilio.type.PhoneNumber;

@Component
@Aspect
public class SMSService {

    @Value("${twilio.sms.authentication_Id:80b7c5a8b73a26a9b588a906d54269c3}")
    private String authenticationId;
    @Value("${twilio.sms.account_sid:AC038d9532222b3d39fce4b43a5dce9ce1}")
    private String accountId;
    @Value("${twilio.sms.from_number:+12566662741}")
    private String fromNumber;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        Twilio.init(accountId, authenticationId);
    }

    @AfterReturning(pointcut = "execution(* com.naresh.service.impl.CustomerServiceImpl.save(..)) && args(customerDTO,..)", returning = "custId")
    public void sendSMS(JoinPoint joinPt, CustomerDTO customerDTO, Long custId) {

        Message.creator(new PhoneNumber(customerDTO.getMobile()), new PhoneNumber(fromNumber),
                "Customer " + custId + " registered successfully...").create();
    }

    @AfterReturning(pointcut = "execution(* com.naresh.service.impl.AccountServiceImpl.createAccount(..))", returning = "accDTO")
    public void sendSMSAcc(JoinPoint joinPt, AccountDTO accDTO) {

        CustomerDTO customerDTO = accDTO.getCustomer();

        Message.creator(new PhoneNumber(customerDTO.getMobile()), new PhoneNumber(fromNumber),
                "Hi " + customerDTO.getName() + ", Your " + accDTO.getAccountType() + " account " + accDTO.getAccNo()
                        + " has been registered with us successfully.Your balance is " + accDTO.getBalance())
                .create();
    }

}
```

The above is working fine if the account creation task is successful. But if we are getting any error, at that time also success sms is received by the customer.

Please help me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

`@AfterReturning` advice, according to the [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/aop/AfterReturningAdvice.html):

> is invoked only on normal method return, not if an exception is thrown.

That means, that your methods `com.naresh.service.impl.CustomerServiceImpl.save` and `com.naresh.service.impl.AccountServiceImpl.createAccount` return some value but doesn't throw any exception. What is the error your are getting? Does this error affects returned value? The only way is to parse the returned value to find out whether something was wrong.

Comment: Let us take an example of Unique key violation. We will not get any exception at the time of save() calling if we are violating unique key. We will get exception at the time of committing the data. In the above scenario, the sms will be triggered before commit itself. If data save to the database is unsuccessful, we should not send sms to the customer. But in my application, sms is triggered.

Comment: In that case you have to change the pointcuts, to get it triggered after the commit or commit it earlier in the save method. It has nothing common with Aspects, but with the buisnes-logic of your application, which is not shown in the question, and the way you use it.

Comment: Hi Stabislav, save() here indicates that spring data jpa save().@Transactional
 public AccountDTO createAccount(AccountDTO accountDTO) {
  Account account = acctRepo.save(convert(accountDTO));
  log.info(account.getAccNo() + " created successfully...");
  
  return convert(account);
 }